# JavaScript "this" changing scope within Prototype functions

Tags: javascript, scope, prototype

Firstly, I'm new to Javascript, so this probably just my misunderstanding so apologies.

I have found that when debugging my Javascript, the value of `this` changes within my prototype methods and causes irregularities else where within the other prototype methods.

It (`this`) starts off with reference to the object for which the method belongs, and then later on it changes to `Window` and when i try to reference method `this.request` in the method `Clarizen.prototype.getSessionId` the browser gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.request is not a function

I checked using Chrome's debugger and the value of `this` changes to Window when it enters this method.

Here is the code:

```js
var Clarizen = function (userName, password, applicationId, optionalSessionId) {
    if (userName === undefined) {
        throw new Error('userName is missing');
    }
    if (password === undefined) {
        throw new Error('password is missing');
    }
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
    this.applicationId = applicationId;
    this.sessionId = (optionalSessionId === undefined) ? '' : optionalSessionId;
    this.constants = ClarizenConstants.Urls;
    this.jsonUser = null;
};


Clarizen.prototype.convertToObject = function(json)
{
    console.log("convertToObject: " + json);
    return JSON.parse(json);
};

Clarizen.prototype.debug = function (message) {
    console.log("clarizen object debug " + message);
};

Clarizen.prototype.validateMethod = function (method) {
    if (method === "GET" || method === "POST" || method === "HEAD") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

Clarizen.prototype.request = function (options) {
    var url = (options.url !== null) ? options.url : null;
    var callback = (typeof options.callback === "function") ? options.callback : null;
    var method = (options.method !== null) ? options.method : "GET";

    if (url === null)
    { throw new Error("url missing"); }

    if (callback === null)
    { throw new Error("callback is missing/not a function type"); }

    if (!Clarizen.prototype.validateMethod(options.method)) {
        throw new Error("method can isnt supported currently " + method)
    }

    var util = new Bradaz();
    var xhr = util.createXHR(url, method, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var response = callback(xhr.responseText);
            return response;
        }
    };

    if (options.body !== null) {
        xhr.send(options.body)
    }
    else {

        xhr.send();
    }
};

Clarizen.prototype.getSessionId = function(response)
{
    var loginResponse = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log("getSessionId " + loginResponse.serverLocation);
    
//The followin ERRORS
    var r = this.request (
        {
            url: this.serverLocation + ClarizenConstants.Urls.authentication,
            method: "POST",
            callback: this.convertToObject,
            body: this.jsonUser
        }
        );   
};

Clarizen.prototype.login = function () {

    var obj = new ClarizenObject();
    var user = obj.factory({
        type: 'User',
        userName: "username",
        password: "password"
    });

    var jsonBody = JSON.stringify(user);
    this.jsonUser = jsonBody;
    var response = this.request (
        {
            url: ClarizenConstants.Urls.getServerDefinition,
            method: "POST",
            callback: this.getSessionId,
            body: jsonBody
        }
        );   
};
```

We enter the object through the `login` prototype method (in pastebin):

```
var clarizen = new Clarizen(user.userName, user.password);
clarizen.login();
```

Comment: Regarding the dupe, one place I saw that will lose the context of `this` is here: `callback: this.getSessionId,` - when the callback is run, `this` will be wrong within `getSessionId`.  It can be fixed with `callback: this.getSessionId.bind(this)`.

Comment: James you beautiful man - thanks for the speedy reply I will test tonight

Comment: See the section *"Common problem: Using object methods as callbacks / event handlers"* in the duplicate.

Comment: I should really get better at finding things on SO first it seems! Cheers guys

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to find something if you don't exactly know what to look for :) No worries!